# Microservice security with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, docker, amazon-ec2

I've got an ECS cluster where I have a couple of services running. All of them have their own load balancer so for every service I have a URL like **`http://my-service-1234554321.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com`**. But I would like to open only one service of all these (f.ex. 10) services for the whole world while all the others I would like to be hidden and have access to them only from services in this cluster via HTTP. Is it possible and how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Load Balancers can be either be `internet facing` (open to traffic from the Internet) or `internal` facing (accepting traffic from within a VPC).

When you create the load balancer for your service, specify the scheme as `internal` for the services you only wish to access from within the cluster. For the service that needs to be external, set it as `internet facing`.

The ECS documentation talks about setting the Load Balancer scheme [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/create-application-load-balancer.html).

Just remember that a load balancer cannot be both `internet facing` and `internal` at the same time. If you decide that you want to expose services that were internal over the Internet at a later date, you will probably need to create a second `internet facing` ELB for that.

Comment: And I cannot set some routes to be `internal` and some `internet` facing?

Comment: Internal/external Is an attribute of the entire balancer.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - sqlbot I mean, is it possible to use 2 load balancers for one service: `internet` facing for routes `/api/*` and `internal` for routes `/some-route/*`